# TFS 2015 - Process configuration file shows duplicate states

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I added a new state to the bug work item but now the states in the  feedbackrequestworkitems section keeps duplicating when I import the process configuration. I remove the duplicate, import again and it duplicates again.

Example:

```
<FeedbackRequestWorkItems category="Microsoft.FeedbackResponseCategory" pluralName="Feedback Responses" singularName="Feedback Response">
    <States>
      <State type="InProgress" value="Active" />
      <State type="InProgress" value="Active" />
      <State type="Complete" value="Closed" />
      <State type="Complete" value="Closed" />
    </States>
  </FeedbackRequestWorkItems>
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this keeps duplicating and more importantly how to prevent it?Thank you.